# Error in R : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am using affy package to process affymetrix data of Plasmodium falciparum obtained from http://carrier.gnf.org/publications/CellCycle/ as raw CEL data in R
and normalizing by rma method. The chip description file is also available from the link mentioned. The cdf package was created using "makecdfenv" package.

While processing I came across the error

```
> mydata
AffyBatch object
size of arrays=712x712 features (12 kb)
cdf=tsrimalariacdf (5337 affyids)
number of samples=7
number of genes=5337
annotation=tsrimalariacdf
notes=

> eset <-rma(mydata)
Error in exprs(object)[index, , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
```

Any help is appreciated

Thank You

Comment: Please provide us with a reproducible example, in this case we are missing the data needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Posting on the Bioconductor [mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/mailform/) (no subscription required) will generate an authoritative answer quickly.